# Spring Boot Dockerfile error: unknown instruction: JAVA

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile that I'm trying to use to containerize my Spring Boot application:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as myservice

COPY build/libs/my-service.jar my-service.jar

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail https://localhost:9200/healthCheck || exit 1

EXPOSE 443 9200

ENTRYPOINT [
    "java", \
    "-Dspring.config=.", \
    "-Dspring.profiles.active=local", \
    "-Dkeystore.file=mykey.p12, \
    "-jar", \
    "my-service.jar"
]
```

When I run:

```
docker build -t myorg/my-service .
```

I get:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   82.5MB
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 10: unknown instruction: "JAVA",
```

**What's going on here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reading "java" as a separate Dockerfile instruction. You need to escape the first line of your entrypoint command after `[` and on your last line before `]` if you want them to be on separate lines:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ \
    ... \
]
```

Like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ \
    "java", \
    "-Dspring.config=.", \
    "-Dspring.profiles.active=local", \
    "-Dkeystore.file=mykey.p12, \
    "-jar", \
    "my-service.jar" \
]
```

I recommend using a linter to catch errors like this. `hadolint` is a good command-line linter and you can easily download Dockerfile linters for most IDEs.

Comment: Wow, that was it, thanks @tentative (+1). Funny you mention linters, I'm paying for a commercial version of IntelliJ and have downloaded and installed the Docker/Dockerfile plugin and it says my (bad) Dockerfile is perfectly fine. But you're right, adding those backslashes fixes everything -- thanks again!